# Annoying blank window in MacVim - how to get rid of it?

Tags: macos, macvim

Whenever I start MacVim, a window opens that is not a buffer and doesn't seem to do anything - it doesn't react to any input at all, even - and that is the annoying part - the Mac OS X close button doesn't do anything. The window is just there and silently stares at me.

[image]

I already tried installing MacVim from scratch and completely deleting all .vim* configs, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you typing to open MacVim? Or are you using a shortcut?

Comment: Did you remove the .vimrc file as well? located in your Mac OS X user home directory? It is separate from the .vim/ directory that is also in your home directory.

Comment: Are you running the latest milestone with Lion capability?  I've noticed older mac apps open lots of windows on Lion because of some weird "open the last window you had open" feature.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you on and what version of MacVim are you running?

Comment: It's MacVim 7.3 on OS X 10.7.3

Comment: The "strange" window opens about 3 seconds after the initial buffer opened, btw.

Comment: Behaviour is the same whether I start the app from the Dock or on the Terminal via Open.

Comment: davetron5000: Sounds reasonable, I'll try to build the latest version available.

Comment: FWIW MacVIM 7.3.260 got rid of most of the Lion oddities for me.

Comment: Where did you get it from? https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/tags only has up to 64 as far as I can see...

Comment: Got it, you were talking about the underlying vim version. I just downloaded the latest snapshot of MacVim (64) from https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/downloads, same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing how you have tried to delete all the normal preference files relating to vim settings, ~/.vimrc, ~/.vim there is one more thing to try and that is the Mac Os App specific preference files for MacVim. One good candidate is the MacVim plist file named `org.vim.MacVim.plist`. A corrupted version of that file may be causing the random window to appear.

First thing quit MacVim.

Then delete the MacVim related plist files.

You can use the terminal and the following command to help find the MacVim preferences related files. `find / -name ".vim."`

The `org.vim.MacVim.plist` file should be located at:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/
```

You might also want to delete:
`org.vim.MacVim.LSSharedFileList.plist`

If the extra 'dead' window problem still exists when you reopen MacVim, then try deleting additionally some more files, this time some Cache and Lion Saved State Related files, along with other related files. Again Quit MacVim before deletion of any of the files, to prevent re-saving of the corrupted state of the program.

I observed the following other MacVim related files in the `find` search results, that you can try deletlting to attempt to resolve the issue:

```
/private/var/db/BootCaches/<XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX>/app.org.vim.MacVim.playlist

/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/org.vim.MacVim

/Users/<username>/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/org.vim.MacVim.savedState
```

Comment: the solution seemed to delete a file called `Library/Preferences/org.vim.MacVim.plist.lockfile`... thank you for the insights